# Recognizable not decidable subset

Tags: logic, computability, formal-languages, turing-machines

Prove that an infinite $(|L|=|\mathbb{N}|) $ language L has an infinite, recognizable and not decidable subset

I have already proved that L has an infinite not recognizable subset A, but I don't know how to do this second part

I have thought about considering B=L\A

And I think it is recognizable because if it weren't then $A \cup B=L$ wouldn't be recognizable either, but I'm not sure about this

Comment: What is the recognizability of a set? It seems not standard terminology.

Comment: A set is recognizable if there is a Turing machine that accepts every element of the set

Comment: @user719961 And that doesn't accept (though doesn't necessarily reject) any elements not in the set.

Comment: The classic example of the sort you're looking for is the halting set.

Comment: The complement doesn’t have to be recognizable. Consider for example the language of Turing Machines accepting the language $\Sigma^*=\{0,1\}^*$, sometimes referred to as $ALL_{TM}$